# Getting error 'Cannot read property 'document' of undefined' while importing exporting.js (to export highchart charts)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to export a highchart charts to a PDF file. For that, I've read that I should use exporting.js (and others libraries). But when I import this library (exporting.js) I get this error: 'Cannot read property 'document' of undefined'.

I import this from a javascript:

```
var newscript = document.createElement('script');
newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
newscript.async = true;
newscript.src = '/resources/tda-ga/js/charts/lib/exporting.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
```

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Please verify if you have the same version of exporting.js and highcharts.js module. It looks like you refer to the newest exporting.js but not up-to-date highcharts.js.

Comment: That's it. I used an older version of exporting.js, and everything went ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Please verify if you have the same version of exporting.js and highcharts.js module. It looks like you refer to the newest exporting.js but not up-to-date highcharts.js.