# Getting error 'Cannot read property 'document' of undefined' (to export highchart charts)

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

As the title suggests, I am trying to import "exporting.js" so that I could use highcharts in my node.js app. I have followed exactly from this site:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts

I have already imported the Highcharts module, but I keep getting document of undefined when I import "exporting.js".

I have already looked at this topic and it did not resolve my problem. 
[Getting error 'Cannot read property 'document' of undefined' while importing exporting.js (to export highchart charts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747535/getting-error-cannot-read-property-document-of-undefined-while-importing-exp)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
(function () {

'use strict';

/**
 * Creates new HighChart
 * @class HighChart
 */
var HighChart = function () {

var Highcharts = require('highcharts');

// Load module after Highcharts is loaded
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', { /*Highcharts options*/ });
```

Thats partially my code but this is where it is failing at. It is not able to require the exporting module.

Comment: Could you show some code? I mean, this: `require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);` should work. Also check [this discussion](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4994).

Comment: @PawełFus I just added some code.

Comment: Well, it works for me. Which version of Highcharts you have? Try 4.2.5. Maybe it's issue with `var Highchart = function() { ... }`? Try to require Highcharts on top of your document.

Comment: @PawełFus I tried 4.2.5 and requiring the module at the top but still no luck. My ultimate goal is basically to use my protractor test to grab data from any highchart model present on any website and download it as a csv. From what I'm understanding, highcharts is only for client side and putting it in nodejs protractor test won't work?

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm missing something, so let's clarify: protractor is end-to-end testing, right? So why do you have Highcharts in nodejs? Shouldn't charts be on the client side? NPM version of Highcharts works great for example with webpack or browserify. Just to be clear: you can require Highcharts in nodejs, that's perfectly fine. You can even try to render Highcharts in backend using virtual DOM.

Comment: @PawełFus Sorry if I'm not being clear. Let me start at the beginning: So I have an application written on the client side. It is just a regular web application. I am using protractor to do end-to-end ui testing on this application, however, protractor is limited to testing highcharts. By the way, protractor is written in nodejs (The tests are written in nodejs). What my main goal is, basically export the highchart data on the web application into csv so I could do some file comparison. However, I'm not sure how to grab the highchart object from the web application to use the exporting.js.

Comment: @PawełFus So I am not trying to render a highchart on nodejs. All I am trying to do is export the highchart thats already rendered on my web application using protractor (nodejs)

Comment: To be honest, I don't see anything wrong with your code, so there must be something else. Are you sure, that the issue comes from loading exporting?  Your error sounds like including `exporting` without Highcharts core. Or trying to create a chart in nodejs, not on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `'use strict'`. This error comes from the `window` object stopping being associated with `this` in global context by strict mode, returning `undefined` instead (which has no `document` property).